# How to update iMovie on Mid 2009 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, imovie

About a year ago I bought a used Mid 2009 MacBook Pro and it came with iMovie. The user before me clearly didn't update iMovie regularly, as the version is 9.0.9.

I know i can update it to 10.1.1, but since the person didn't update it regularly, new versions of iMovie have come out, that are not compatible with my Mac. How can I update iMovie to 10.1.1 because 10.1.6 is not compatible with my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you are asking however if iMovie will update to the latest version on your Mac there is a hack (that I used on Sierra) that lets you run the latest version of iMovie. I would make a copy of iMovie first, in case something goes awry. But [this trick](http://blog.iharder.net/2015/01/23/run-imovie-hd-and-maybe-other-older-applications-in-yosemite/), worked for me.

It involves a simple script and some Terminal work but is not especially difficult, if you can get the current version installed on your Mac.

But to be sure make a copy of your current version and if it updates, a copy of the new version too. If it goes south you can revert!